# Ajax.BeginForm is submitting disabled form elements

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-ajax, http-post, ajax.beginform

Using MVC3 and Ajax.BeginForm I surprisingly discovered that mvc ajax forms submits elements with the attribute disabled="disabled".

I have tested both select and text inputs.

I was suprised because they should not be submited and they will not when using Html.BeginForm.

Is there some hidden option or a workaround for this?

[EDIT example]

```
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Action", "Control", new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "POST" }))
{

  <input type="text" name="_enabled" value="_enabled" />
  <input type="text" name="_disabled" value="_disabled" disabled="disabled" />

  <input type="submit" value="POST" />

}
```

[image: Posted data]

Html.BeginForm will not post the _disabled value.

Comment: I just tested and they are not submitted.  may be you have to post some code.

Comment: What is the HTTP Log Viewer? I never used that. I checked in firefox and IE things works fine.

Comment: Log viewer is and addon for IE.
I used IE developer tools also, same thing.

Comment: Looking in the MicrosoftMvcAjac.debug.js the Sys.Mvc.MvcHelpers._serializeForm function seems to not filter elements that are disabled. It only checks for the existance of a name attribute.
jQuery.serialize() does however

Answer (score 0):

you can set disabled element value in other hidden element:

```
<input type="text" name="Id" id="Id" value="5" />

<input type="hidden" name="Id" id="Id" value="5" />
```

and or :

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Id)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
```